# I need to un-unicode something in python

Tags: python, unicode, arcpy

i input "company\data\2012\name" to a variable.

i get "company\dataü2\name" in that variable.

i want "company\data\2012\name" in that variable.

i am using arcpy as part of esri's arcmap python scripting with a geoprocessing toolbox that i think handles the string literal part of my inputs if that makes sense to anyone.

Help!

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you want and what you have now?

Comment: You really need to fix this problem at the source, not try to bandaid it later. Comments on the existing answers indicate it's not coming from a literal. How did that garbage get into the variable in the first place?

Comment: i don't know if you are familiar with arcpy but it has a gui that i can set data input types and i set this one as a folder type. somehow it messes up and throws in that odd character.

Comment: Why do you keep saying you can't  just escape the strings in the commnents to the answers? That does not seen likely - a string read from a file or a database, or a web request would not be processed like that: the behavior you describe happens when the strings are typed into the source code. Please detail how you are getting those strings into your program.

Comment: Maybe you are using Python2's `input` to get the strings? If so, just replace it for `raw_input` (and stop typing in the quotes when you enter the values)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to include a literal backslash in your string.  Backslash is used as an escape character in Python strings so to include a literal backslash you need to do one of the following:

- Use two backslashes, e.g. `"data\\2012"`
- Use a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), e.g. `r"data\2012"`

With `"data\2012"`, the `"\201"` is actually interpreted as an octal escape, so that escape sequence is translated into a single character.  The value 201 in base 8 is 129 in base 10 or 0x81 in hex.  If you are seeing 'ü' when this is displayed you must be using a Windows console that uses [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or some similar codec.

Comment: i can't do that. is there anyway to convert the "dataü2" to "data\2012"?

Comment: You should never need to do that.  If you want a backslash in a Python string you have to escape it or use a raw string literal.  If you can't use a raw string literal because of some other tool you are using, escaping the backslash using `\\` in the string should work.

Comment: It oucrred me that maybe the OP is using Python's 2 input - that would  explain the " I can't do that" - @J-roc, just check my last comment on the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

The number is still there, it's just in the string.
This may not get you 100% of the way there, but it should be close.
Basically, you need to determine the set of valid characters you don't want 'decoded', and then translate the rest like this:

```
# Original escaped the \n correctly?? but not the \201....
testdata = "company\data\2012\\name" 
print testdata
company\dataü2\name
corrected = ''.join([x if (x.isalnum() or x in '/.\\') else '\\%s'%(oct(ord(x))[1:]) for x in testdata])
print corrected
```

You may need to add to the list of recognized punctuation, and/or limit the range of the numbers that it recognizes.

However, you really do need to fix it at the source... this won't help with something like this:

```
testdata = 'company\data\015\\name'
print testdata
\nameny\data
```

or worse

```
testdata = 'company\data\102\\name'
print testdata
company\dataB\name
```

I have to know that I should translate a character back to be able for this to work. `\201` works, because it's not an otherwise expected character. The first one may be ok - we don't really expect carriage returns either. But how would I know to convert the B? it's a valid alphabetic character, and I can't tell it apart from the rest of the real text.

So, this really needs to be resolved upstream.

Comment: What are you  saying? I mean, at all? It is just a question of escaping the `\`s, or using a raw string.

Comment: It sounded like that wasn't a choice - he's using a third party module with external data, and that's processing the above incorrectly. This might let him salvage what he's got without having to go fix the external module. Which is also an option, of course.